# HTML Text Scraping

Tags: jquery, html, css, screen-scraping

I'm a fervent reader of web-novels. I main read on my phone. To my annoyance not every site has a dark/light switcher, no sans-serif/serif font switcher, and/or option to change the font size. Some sites don't even have next/previous chapter buttons. So my plan was to make my own little website in which I could read them one by one having all the options I want. Now I know how to change themes, switch fonts and their sizes. However getting the chapters themselves has proven to be quite a struggle.

First I wanted to use jquery, but while I could change the width the height didn't change for unknown reasons.
E.g. $("#siteloader").html(''); With css width/height 100%.

I also didn't know how to remove the useless clutter to just be left with the links and text. So I decided to try a different approach.

I know there is a site called textise which leaves just the text. I wanted to create something similar. I found out about web scraping. However I can't find anyway to scrape just text from a website using jquery. I've found a PHP image scraper to use as example, but I've not played around with PHP much.

So my question is does anyone know an example/tutorial where someone does something similar to what I want in jquery?

Anyway I'd be really thankful if anyone could help me, this is my first time asking a question on here, so if I did anything wrongly, please tell me so I know what I can change in future questions.

Comment: You can't just scrape text with PHP. You can use something like [cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) and then parse it using a library like [SimpleDOM](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) to extract only the parts you need.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [ask] and [what's on-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [what's not](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Asking for external resources is off-topic.

Comment: Firefox has a an option called "[reader view](https://www.google.gr/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0ahUKEwiQ3bb-grXSAhWCvBQKHW-MC40QFggaMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fsupport.mozilla.org%2Fen-US%2Fkb%2Ffirefox-reader-view-clutter-free-web-pages&usg=AFQjCNEWkqDoN09MlGV31oAk2qaq8y1cQw&sig2=Qm01uDayYhkO8BTfaeddsw&cad=rja)" which might help you.

Answer (score 0):

I've worked on something similar that might be useful to you. With a Httprequest you can get HTML from an external resource. I used it to extract a certain image.

```
$.ajaxPrefilter( function (options) {
  if (options.crossDomain && jQuery.support.cors) {
    var http = (window.location.protocol === 'http:' ? 'http:' : 'https:');
    options.url = http + '//cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/' + options.url;
  }
});

var url = 'https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2017/01/redesigning-the-paris-metro-map/';

$.get(
    url,
    function (data) {
        var html = $(data);
      var article = html.find('article');
      console.log(article);
      $('#content').html(article);
});
```

In this example I search for an article tag. Problem is, the page you might want to extract the "web-novel" from might not contain an article tag.

https://jsfiddle.net/PaulvdDool/bra6v6rL/15/

I ran into the same problem extracting an image. The best result would be an `og:image` declared in the meta tags. But else I would need to extract the first image from the article, or the image used in the header.
I found out a lot of resources use the article tag or a div with the id `content`. I just iterated through all these possibilities; if there is no og:image, search for an article tag, if there isn't an article tag see if there is a div with id `content` and so on. If all else would fail, to bad, no image.
You might want to do something similar.

I encourage you try making this yourself. Practice. Improve your skills. But I just want to mention you can also use read-later apps like Pocket or Instapaper.